# How to Retrieve the password from the password text box

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to retrieve the password from the password text box. I tried by using below code but it's not working.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).getAttribute("value")
```

This is the HTML code of the input:

```
<input type="password"
      placeholder="Password"
      class="input identityinput"
      id="password"
      name="pw"
      onkeypress="checkCaps(event)"
      autocomplete="off"
      onkeyup="if(this.value != ''){
                document.getElementById('clrPw').style.display='block';
               } else {
                document.getElementById('clrPw').style.display='none';
               }">
```

Comment: Can you provide more detailes on "it's not working'? and why is your type `email` the label `username` if you are speaking about your `password`field?

Comment: Hi bish, sorry the actual html is: <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="input identityinput" id="password" name="pw" onkeypress="checkCaps(event)" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="if(this.value != ''){document.getElementById('clrPw').style.display='block';}else{document.getElementById('clrPw').style.display='none';}">

Comment: Hi bish, The above html from salesforce login page.

Answer (score 1):

You search for the wrong id:

You search for id `Passwd` but your field has the id `password` so change the statement to:

```
 By.id("password"))
```